# RequestHandler with edismax ignore Synonyms and Stopwords

Tags: search, solr, solrcloud

I have the following query defined in my `solrconfig.xml`:

```
  <requestHandler name="/defaultSearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- Adds filters to all queries-->
    <lst name="appends">
      <str name="fq">-DELETED:true</str>
    </lst>

    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin -->
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <!-- As dismax is used, 0.00 = is pure dismax , 1.00 = sum -->
      <float name="tie">1.00</float>
      <!-- Query Fields - Search fileds with its height -->
      <str name="qf">
        DocumentDisplayName^10 DocumentName^9
        DocumentContent^5 DocumentDescription^3 DocumentTAGS^8
      </str>
      <!-- Phrase Field - frases fields used on quer as phrase >> "" -->
      <str name="pf">
        DocumentDisplayName^10 DocumentName^9
        DocumentContent^5 DocumentDescription^3 DocumentTAGS^8
      </str>
      <!-- See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin -->
      <str name="mm">
        2&lt;-1 5&lt;-2 6&lt;90%
      </str>
      <!-- Phrase whitespace ignore -->
      <int name="ps">10</int>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

It works pretty fine, but, it just ignore my stopwords and synonyms files.

I can't understand what is happening, and have no idea on how to fix it.
Any help?

---

## Edit

[Query used, result (with debug=true) and the interesting part of schema.xml](https://gist.github.com/caarlos0/4ad53583fb2b30ef0bec)

Comment: How does your schema config look like ? What queries are you firing ? Give us more examples.

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for help and sorry for the insufficient information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the query without wildcards 'solve' the issue for now.

Thanks.